# Windows forms and scaling

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, scale

I've just set my Windows 10 scaling to 125% because it's more readable to me as a developer. When I opened Visual Studio I get information:

> Scaling on your main display is set to 125%.

It also gives me an option to:

> Restart Visual Studio with 100% scaling.

When I set this option then after Visual Studio restart I see the message:

> Automatic scaling is turned off. WPF/UWP XAML designers might not
>   display correctly.

And also the option to set:

> Restart Visual Studio with automatic scaling

To be honest I lot my mind. I want to be sure that there will be no problems with my windows forms application. Which option then should I choose?

Comment: What does this have to do with C#? This doesn't seem like a very big problem to me. Chose some option(s) and see if you are comfortable using the program and no problems arise. If you aren't satisfied, try something else.

Comment: WPF and UWP apps are DPIAware by default. WinForms is slightly different. You can enable DPIAwareness modifying the `app.manifest` or the `app.config` files. For example: [How to configure an app to run correctly on a machine with a high DPI setting (e.g. 150%)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13228495/7444103). You just need to be *aware* yourself of the difference. Test and see what happens with different configurations (and screens, if possible). Windows 10 and Windows 7 may also behave differently. To test this, too, if you want to also target Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

The messages are about [wpf](/questions/tagged/wpf) and [xaml](/questions/tagged/xaml). Since you are using [winforms](/questions/tagged/winforms) you should just pick whatever you like best to work with.

Obviously, you should test your application with different settings and on different machines to make sure it works as you expect it to work. But that should be the default anyway.

Comment: What should i set as default first or second option? To me i prefer when 125% is ok but i do not want win form windows during design to be fine on other computer when deploy.